# IDEA: each test run creates an empty file in project directory

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run a JUnit test in IDEA, an empty file appears in project directory. The file is named according to the following pattern: .attach_pidNNNNN, for example `.attach_pid6710`.

If a run a usual Java application (using `main()` method), no such files appear.

This has started recently, probably after the upgrade to version 2018.3.

Is this ok? It is a bit irritating to remove these files manually all the time.

PS. What happened to the test green line? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roman, please follow already created issue at YouTrack for this topic: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202129

Please clarify what's wrong with the test green line (if possible attach the screenshot)?

Comment: Thank you Olga! As for the green/red bar, I this issue is also already created, I've just found it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200548 The thing is that it's actually a lot easier to spot a green bar than a small green icon.